# MySQL Escape Characters

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm getting an SQL error when trying to mix a `match against` in a SQL statement with a specific character which is not covered by MySQL escape functions in PHP.

This is an example:

The name to search is: `Tommy -`

The generated (error) query is:

```
Select * 
From users
Where match(name,username) 
            Against('+tommy -*' in boolean     
                          mode)
```

What is the best way to fix it, and why the `mysql_escape` functions don't cover it?

Answer (score 2):

```
MATCH(...) AGAINST('+tommy' IN ...)
    AND ... LIKE '%tommy -%'
```

That is, use `FULLTEXT` to do what it does best (search for words), then check the results against something more complex via `LIKE` or `REGEXP`.

Granted, it will take some intelligence in your app code to construct the suitable combination of MATCH and [R]LIKE.  But the result is fast and cover a lot more than FULLTEXT can do by itself.

Note:  The optimizer will do the MATCH first, then filter on the other stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Anyway, there is really absolutely no way to just escape the -? A code overhaul is a bit of a problem

Comment: `FULLTEXT` does _some_ things well.  Sorry, it does not do all the odd case that people come up with.  If changing the code is a problem, then you have the wrong platform -- I _often_ find that 3rd party tools get in the way of performance.

Comment: Yea the platform is terrible but i thought there might be a way to fix it without changing the query apart from an escape character. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

PHP's mysql escape functions are probably not FULLTEXT aware.

The MySQL Documentation says about the [**Double Quotes in Booelan Mode Fulltext Searching**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

> '"some words"'
>
> Find rows that contain the exact phrase “some words” (for example, rows that contain “some words of wisdom” but not “some noise words”).
>
> Note
>   The “"” characters that enclose the phrase are operator characters that delimit the phrase. They are not the quotation marks that enclose the search string itself.

If you are looking for `Tommy -`, then sound it in double quotes and separate it from `*`

```
Select * 
From users
Where match(name,username) 
            Against('+"tommy -"*' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: But it seems like that would change the result of the search in other cases, for example 'hello world' will provide a different set of result compared to '"hello world"', and thats something i dont want to happen. There is a way to fix the issue while keeping other searches the same?